# Matlab-Minimum error entropy is used to identify sparse systems

Tags: filter

Professor Principe defined a robust cost function based on quadratic Renyi entropy, namely the minimum error entropy (MEE) criterion. As a robust cost function, MEE is often used in non-Gaussian adaptive filtering algorithms.
Assuming the probability density function of random variable X is, the Renyi quadratic entropy is defined as:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylHzB.png)
Since the probability density function cannot be obtained, Parzen window estimation method is often used to calculate px in practice(x). Suppose the data set is {x1,x2... ,xN}, then the estimated value of its probability density function is:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0eg7.png)
Where N is the number of samples, k (·) represents the kernel function, and σ represents the kernel width.
The commonly used kernel function is Gaussian kernel function
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVog8.png)
The objective function of MEE can be obtained as
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J57hX.png)
ZAMEE algorithm filter weight coefficient updating relation
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHKze.png)

There is a big problem in the code I wrote in MATLAB, I would like to ask the big guys how to modify it.

```
clc;
clear all
close all
mu=.0003;
sample=2000;
epsi=250;                                      
ro=.0007;                                      
q=12;                                          
sigma=2;                                       
p=0.0001;
alpharad=1.6;
noise=zeros(sample,1);
for it=1:sample
    cc0=31; cc=0; a1=alpharad-1;
    while cc0>30
        while cc<0.000001
            v=pi*(rand-0.5);
            cc1=log(cos(a1*v));
            cc=cos(v);
        end
        w=-log(rand);
        cc=log(cc);
        cc0=a1*(log(w)-cc1)-cc;
    end
    xx=abs(sin(alpharad*v))*exp(cc0/alpharad);
    if rand<0.5, xx=-xx; end
    noise(it)=xx;
end
plot((1:sample),noise);

for itr=1:200

    x=randn(1,sample);

    sys=[zeros(1,4) 1 zeros(1,11)];
    
    sys_tap2=zeros(1,length(sys));        
    model2=zeros(1,length(sys));            
    model_tap2=zeros(1,length(model2));
    sys_out2=zeros(1,sample);
    model_out2=zeros(1,sample);
    err2=zeros(1,sample);
    for ii = q : sample
        for jj = 1 : q
            sys_tap2=[x(ii - q + jj) sys_tap2(1:end-1)];
            sys_out2(ii - q + jj)=sys_tap2*sys'+noise(ii - q + jj);
            model_tap2=[x(ii - q + jj)  model_tap2(1:end-1)];
            model_out2(ii - q + jj)=model_tap2*model2';

            err2(jj) = sys_out2(ii - q + jj) - model_out2(ii - q + jj);
        end
        err0=err2(q);
        x0=sys_out2(q);
        ka=0;
        for kk=2:q
            ek=err2(q-kk+1);
            xk=sys_out2(q-kk+1);
            ka=ka+(1/(2*sigma*sqrt(pi)))*exp(-((err0-ek).^2)/(4*sigma.^2))*(err0-ek)*(x0-xk);
        end
        model2=model2+(mu/(2*sigma^2*q^2))*ka;
        mdl4(ii,:)=model2;
    end
    for iii=1:q
        mdl4(iii,:)=0;
    end
    for s=1:sample  % MSD calculation at each input index

        E4(itr,s)=mean((sys-mdl4(s,:)).^2);
    end

    itr
end

figure;
plot(1:length(x),10*log10(mean(E4)))
legend('ZAMEE');
xlabel('Iterations');
ylabel('MSD (dB)');
```